# React native redux storage migration

Tags: react-native, react-redux, migration

On my app, i currently use the AsyncStorage as my redux storage, but i have problems caused of a lot of data and the 6Mb limit is not enough. I want to upgrade my project to a newer react version and with that i want to migrate to another redux storage like FilesystemStorage so the transition for users to be smooth(currently if i change the storage the redux recreates from the start). How can i achieve this cause i can't find any learning materials.

**My current code is this**

```
export default function configureStore(onCompletion: () => void): any {


const persistConfig = {
    key: App.name,
    storage,
    //   storage: FilesystemStorage,
    //   storage: FSStorage(),
    blacklist: ['app'],
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2, // see "Merge Process" section for details.
  };



return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
try {
  const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, promise));

  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, enhancer);

  var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
  // Apply env change for dev, due to library dev issues
  if (environment != 'production') {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
  }
  persistStore(store, null, () => resolve(store));
  if (environment != 'production') {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
  }
} catch (e) {
  reject(e);
}


});
}
```

*react: 16.8.6,
react-native: 0.59.10,
react-redux: ^7.1.0,
redux: ^4.0.1,
redux-persist: ~5.10.0*

**And my updated code is this**

```
export default function configureStore(onCompletion: () => void): any {


const persistConfig = {
    key: App.name,
    //storage,
    storage: FilesystemStorage,
    //   storage: FSStorage(),
    blacklist: ['app'],
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2, // see "Merge Process" section for details.
  };



return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
try {
  const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, promise));

  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, enhancer);

  var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
  // Apply env change for dev, due to library dev issues
  if (environment != 'production') {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
  }
  persistStore(store, null, () => resolve(store));
  if (environment != 'production') {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
  }
} catch (e) {
  reject(e);
}


});
}
```

*react: 16.13.1,
react-native: 0.63.2,
react-redux: ^7.2.1,
redux: ^4.0.5,
redux-persist: 6.0.0*